# Expressing sums with generating functions

Tags: summation, generating-functions

Knowing that $A(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix^i, B(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_ix^i, C(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}c_ix^i$ express $$$$
a) $C$ as a function of $A$ and $B$ when $c_n=\sum_{j+2k\le n}a_jb_k $,
b) A as a function of $B$ when $nb_n=\sum_k^n2^k\frac{a_k}{(n-k)!}$

It is an exercise from the topic of generating functions, but is there a trivial connection between those 2?

Comment: I don't think so, the two answers don't look related and you don't need (a) to solve (b). 
Hints: if $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k z^k$, then $\frac{f(z)}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\sum_{\ell=0}^k f_\ell) z^k$ and $zf'(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (kf_k)z^k$.

Comment: So is a) $C(x)=A(x)*(x^2*B(x))$. No, it won't. I want to produce only even terms of $b_n$.

Comment: a) should be $C(x) = \frac{A(x)B(x^2)}{1-x}$. The appearance of $2k$ instead of $k$ in the condition $j+2k \le n$ is equivalent to replacing $B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k$ by $B(x^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^{2k}$ in constructing $C(x)$.